# Line matching and the "n" (next) command in Vim

Tags: vim, match

I often use the search pattern atom `\%<nr>l.` to match lines or `\%<nr>c.` to match columns.

Does anybody know why I can't use the `n` (next) command to go to the next match if I use these atoms?

For example, consider `/\%4l.\|\%6l.` (matches line 4 and line 6). With the cursor on line 4, pressing `n` doesn't move the cursor to line 6; it merely goes to the next character.

Is there a way to go the next match in a single key press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `/\%4l.\|\%6l.` prescribes to match any character on the
fourth line, or any character on the sixth line. After the first
character of the fourth line is matched, the next occurrence of this
pattern would be the second character of the same line, then the one
after that and so on until the last character on that line. It moves
to the sixth line only when all the characters on the fourth line has
been matched.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to go "next" line?

Comment: @Remonn: Not knowing what problem you are trying to solve, I would suggest the following modification of the pattern: `^\%4l\|^\%6l`. Any other pattern that specifies a particular position on the matching lines (e.g. `\%4l\_$\|\%6l\_$` or `\%4l\%5c\|\%6l\%3c`) would also work.

Comment: hi ib, you gave me an even simpler solution: $n (go to end of line, n)

Comment: @Remonn: Yes, if specific line numbers (like 4 and 6 here) is not important, you can search just for beginning or ending of a line (which any line has).